# symfony 2 doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I create method for select current premises foto, all works good

```
public function findByDistrictIds($criteria)
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->
            createQuery('SELECT f.id, f.path FROM RealestateCoreBundle:Foto f WHERE f.premises in (:criteria)');
    $q->setParameter('criteria', $criteria);
    return $q->getResult();
}
```

but when I add to select command "f.premises", get error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 23 near 'premises FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

How i can get foto with premises_id? And how use "WHERE IN" clause in queryBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. This came up recently. Premises is a relation field so you need to do a fetch join. Note the Premises alias `p` in the field list:

```
SELECT f.id, f.path, p 
  FROM RealestateCoreBundle:Foto f 
  JOIN f.premises p 
 WHERE ...
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: just noticed I didn't address the `WHERE IN` part of your question in my answer above... so disregard the `WHERE` part :) I was looking into this yesterday, and you can bind an array of values to a query for a `WHERE IN` clause at the DBAL layer (with `executeQuery()` but I'm not sure about DQL/QueryBuilder. Of course, if the number of parameters does not vary then I'm sure you can bind each value individually: `WHERE q.name IN (:foo, :bar, :baz)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but don't work :) `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 131 near 'p 
': Error: Identification Variable RealestateCoreBundle:Premises used in join path expression but was not defined before.`

Comment: Of course... Doing this from memory. I messed up a little. Sorry about that! The join should be `JOIN f.premises p`, assuming `premises` is the `inversedBy` name you used in your annotations. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, all works. And I mistaken in relation from foto to premises (before `inversedBy="foto"`, now `inversedBy="fotos"`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function findByDistrictIds($criteria)
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->
    createQuery('SELECT f.id, f.path FROM RealestateCoreBundle:Foto f WHERE f.premises =     :criteria');
    $q->setParameter('criteria', $criteria);
    return $q->getResult();
}
```

You can try to use `f.premises = :criteria`
instead of `f.premises in (:criteria)`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `WHERE IN` in query builder, you can pass `$criteria` as an array to `setParameter()` method. Also make sure that array is in this format.

```
$criteria = array('1','2','3'); /* correct */

$criteria = array('1,2,3'); /* incorrect. Some people misunderstand this and set the array like this which is incorrect */
```

So your query would be something like this,

```
$q = $this->getEntityManager()->
        createQuery('
                    SELECT f.id, f.path FROM RealestateCoreBundle:Foto f 
                    WHERE f.premises in (:criteria)');
$q->setParameter('criteria', array('1','2','3'));
```

Hope this helps.